# How transfer custom element's state with cloneNode

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

I'm trying to clone a node which contains custom state properties. The problem is that after the element gets cloned, it does not transfer the related properties. I found a workaround by storing the values as attributes as it seems like they get cloned properly. Is there any workaround to clone more complex properties when the element gets cloned?

Here is a simple example with attribute cloning:

```js
class MyP extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    var shadow = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });

    this.p = document.createElement('p');
    this.p.innerText = this.text;
    shadow.appendChild(this.p);

  }

  get text() {
  
    return this.getAttribute('dataText');
  }

  set text(text) {
    this.p.innerText = text;
    this.setAttribute('dataText', text);
  }
}

customElements.define('my-p', MyP);

document.querySelector('my-p').text = 'Hiding in the shadows';


document.body.append(document.querySelector('my-p').cloneNode(true));
```

```html
<my-p></my-p>
```

Example where the property is not cloned:

```js
class MyP extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    var shadow = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });

    this.p = document.createElement('p');
    this.p.innerText = this._text;
    shadow.appendChild(this.p);

  }

  get text() {
  
    return this._text;
  }

  set text(text) {
    this.p.innerText = text;
    this._text = text;
  }
}

customElements.define('my-p', MyP);

document.querySelector('my-p').text = 'Hiding in the shadows';


document.body.append(document.querySelector('my-p').cloneNode(true));
```

```html
<my-p></my-p>
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) says:           ,   () . It is  ``cloneNode`` not ``copyNode``. So all properties you have to copy yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `dataset` gets cloned also properly, which I think is better than using attributes. Also if you have complex data structure stored in the dataset, you can check the value in the constructor and if it has value you can be sure that the element was cloned and you might need to deep copy that structure.

```js
class MyP extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    var shadow = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });

    this.p = document.createElement('p');
    this.p.innerText = this.text;
    shadow.appendChild(this.p);

  }

  get text() {
  
    return this.dataset.dataText;
  }

  set text(text) {
    this.p.innerText = text;
    this.dataset.dataText = text;
  }
}

customElements.define('my-p', MyP);

document.querySelector('my-p').text = 'Hiding in the shadows';


document.body.append(document.querySelector('my-p').cloneNode(true));
```

```html
<my-p></my-p>
```